# EKS basic auth from Internet

Tags: authentication, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

The problem:
I have WWW application in EKS cluster which I want to be guarded by similar to Basic Auth solution to prevent from temporarily accessing it. This application has some dev accounts configured and we don't want to allow anyone to access, before bypassing the first authentication method (common to all persons which we allow to access it).

Application uses ALB:

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: ...
```

So far possible solutions:

- use nginx with basic auth as proxy (requires deployment change, as there is no nginx in image or deployment - possible but then need to maintain 2 deployments)
- Cognito authentication - possible but I think bit too difficult to configure for temporary solution
- ServiceAccounts - not possible to use because application is exposed on Internet
- VPN access / IP allow/deny - don't know if it's possible to do it on EKS, don't know if client will always use same IP

Can you suggest the simplest solution, not need to be most secure one as I said for now even basic auth to EKS will be enough?